# How can I do DNS lookups in Python, including referring to /etc/hosts?

Tags: python, dns

[dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org) will do my DNS lookups very nicely, but it entirely ignores the contents of `/etc/hosts`.

Is there a python library call which will do the right thing? ie check first in `etc/hosts`, and only fall back to DNS lookups otherwise?

Comment: I created an issue for that: https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/issues/149

Comment: dnspython will not implement this. For simple forward lookups, use the proposed `socket.gethostbyname`, for more complex queries, use dnspython.

Comment: If you're on Linux with systemd, have dnspython use `127.0.0.53` as the dns server which should respect `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I'm not really sure if you want to do DNS lookups *yourself* or if you just want a host's ip. In case you want the latter,

> /!\ socket.gethostbyname is deprecated, prefer [socket.getaddrinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805231/_/66000439#66000439)

from `man gethostbyname`:

> The gethostbyname*(), gethostbyaddr*(), [...] functions are obsolete.  Applications should use getaddrinfo(3),  getnameinfo(3),

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname('localhost')) # result from hosts file
print(socket.gethostbyname('google.com')) # your os sends out a dns query
```

Comment: Does anyone know at which level this lookup is cached?  Within Python?  Or OS?  Or DNS server?

Comment: @Simon Not cached by Python, nor the OS. It depends on any DNS server involved if it caches or not. – Generally speaking: DNS is cached only by the application itself, or by resolving-DNS-servers tucked in the resolving chain.

Comment: @Jochen if “localhost” comes from the hosts file or not depends on the configuration!

Comment: @RobertSiemer Sorry for the late comment: the result *may* be cached by the local resolver. `nscd` and `nslcd` on Unix boxes can do this. It could also be cached by a local name server configured for caching (a common setup, once upon a time. Probably not so much now). It's not a straightforward ‘no’ answer, unfortunately. These things rarely are. :)

Comment: this will only ever return a single address no? So if you have a dns round robin this will not expose all addresses associated with the hostname.

Comment: @ThorSummoner socket.gethostbyname follows the round-robin, subsequent calls give diverse answers

Comment: For the record `socket.gethostbyname` in _Python_ is not deprecated (as of 3.10 and 3.11-dev). You're referencing the man pages of Linux binaries, not Python libraries.

Answer (score 104):

The normal name resolution in Python works fine. Why do you need DNSpython for that. Just use [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html)'s `getaddrinfo` which follows the rules configured for your operating system (on Debian, it follows `/etc/nsswitch.conf`):

```
>>> print(socket.getaddrinfo('google.com', 80))
[(10, 1, 6, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::63', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 2, 17, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::63', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 3, 0, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::63', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 1, 6, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::68', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 2, 17, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::68', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 3, 0, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::68', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 1, 6, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::93', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 2, 17, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::93', 80, 0, 0)), (10, 3, 0, '', ('2a00:1450:8006::93', 80, 0, 0)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('209.85.229.104', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('209.85.229.104', 80)), (2, 3, 0, '', ('209.85.229.104', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('209.85.229.99', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('209.85.229.99', 80)), (2, 3, 0, '', ('209.85.229.99', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('209.85.229.147', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('209.85.229.147', 80)), (2, 3, 0, '', ('209.85.229.147', 80))]
```

Comment: would be nice to add the transformation step. 
`addrs = [ str(i[4][0]) for i in socket.getaddrinfo(name, 80) ]` gives me the list of ips.

Comment: my request result returns the same ip address multiple times; we can fix that with a simple change to alex's suggestion: `addrs = { str(i[4][0]:i for i in socket.getaddrinfo(name, 80) }` returns a dict that includes the unique ips as keys with the rest of the result paired.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you don't want to resolve DNS yourself. `dnspython` is a standalone DNS client that will understandably ignore your operating system because it's bypassing the operating system's utilities.

We can look at a shell utility named `getent` to understand how the (Debian 11-like) operating system resolves DNS for programs. This is likely the standard for all *nix like systems that use a socket implementation.

See `man getent`'s "hosts" section, which mentions the use of `getaddrinfo`, which we can see as `man getaddrinfo`.

To use it in Python, we have to extract some info from the data structures:

```py
import socket

def get_ipv4_by_hostname(hostname):
    # see `man getent` `/ hosts `
    # see `man getaddrinfo`

    return list(
        i        # raw socket structure
            [4]  # internet protocol info
            [0]  # address
        for i in 
        socket.getaddrinfo(
            hostname,
            0  # port, required
        )
        if i[0] is socket.AddressFamily.AF_INET  # ipv4

        # ignore duplicate addresses with other socket types
        and i[1] is socket.SocketKind.SOCK_RAW  
    )

print(get_ipv4_by_hostname('localhost'))
print(get_ipv4_by_hostname('google.com'))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list( map( lambda x: x[4][0], socket.getaddrinfo( \
     'www.example.com.',22,type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)))
```

gives you a list of the addresses for www.example.com.  (ipv4 and ipv6)

Answer (score 3):

This code works well for returning all of the IP addresses that might belong to a particular URI. Since many systems are now in a hosted environment (AWS/Akamai/etc.), systems may return several IP addresses. The lambda was "borrowed" from @Peter Silva.

```
def get_ips_by_dns_lookup(target, port=None):
    '''
        this function takes the passed target and optional port and does a dns
        lookup. it returns the ips that it finds to the caller.

        :param target:  the URI that you'd like to get the ip address(es) for
        :type target:   string
        :param port:    which port do you want to do the lookup against?
        :type port:     integer
        :returns ips:   all of the discovered ips for the target
        :rtype ips:     list of strings

    '''
    import socket

    if not port:
        port = 443

    return list(map(lambda x: x[4][0], socket.getaddrinfo('{}.'.format(target),port,type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)))

ips = get_ips_by_dns_lookup(target='google.com')
```

Comment: What's the `'{}.'.format(target)` for? It seems like both `example.com` and `example.com.` work fine.

Comment: @MatthewD.Scholefield The `'{}.'.format(target)` construct could just as easily be replaced with `{target}` but I wanted to leave the original solution, proposed by @Peter Silver intact.

Answer (score 2):

You can dns lookup with python dns module - with [dns.resolver.query()](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolver-class.html#dns.resolver.Resolver.query).

`pip install dnspython`

```py
import urllib.parse
import dns.resolver

try:
    parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    hostname = parsed_url.hostname
    answers = dns.resolver.query(hostname, 'A')
    for rdata in answers:
        print(rdata.address)
except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
    print('ip not found.')
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this way to expand a DNS RR hostname that expands into a list of IPs, into the list of member hostnames:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def expand_dnsname(dnsname):
    from socket import getaddrinfo
    from dns import reversename, resolver
    namelist = [ ]
    # expand hostname into dict of ip addresses
    iplist = dict()
    for answer in getaddrinfo(dnsname, 80):
        ipa = str(answer[4][0])
        iplist[ipa] = 0
    # run through the list of IP addresses to get hostnames
    for ipaddr in sorted(iplist):
        rev_name = reversename.from_address(ipaddr)
        # run through all the hostnames returned, ignoring the dnsname
        for answer in resolver.query(rev_name, "PTR"):
            name = str(answer)
            if name != dnsname:
                # add it to the list of answers
                namelist.append(name)
                break
    # if no other choice, return the dnsname
    if len(namelist) == 0:
        namelist.append(dnsname)
    # return the sorted namelist
    namelist = sorted(namelist)
    return namelist

namelist = expand_dnsname('google.com.')
for name in namelist:
    print name
```

Which, when I run it, lists a few 1e100.net hostnames: