# Get IP address of URL in Python?

Tags: python, http, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I do DNS lookups in Python, including referring to /etc/hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805231/how-can-i-do-dns-lookups-in-python-including-referring-to-etc-hosts)

I'm using Python 2.7 and I'm creating a iptracer with an online API.

I want the user to have the option to type e.g. google.com, http://google.com or [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and then get the IP address of that and add the IP to a variable.

Is it any links or other help anyone can give me?

Comment: Thank you. Im new to python and not got into sockets yet.

Comment: Your answer is here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805231/how-can-i-do-dns-lookups-in-python-including-referring-to-etc-hosts

Regards
Dipak.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
>>> import socket
>>> print socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
74.125.236.52
```

Comment: On Python 3.7 it doesn't work: `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: @aderchox on python 3.7 I've successfully run following: 
`import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname('google.com'))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use gethostbyname_ex() function located in socket module http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html