# Retreiving data from a website

Tags: python

I'm terribly sorry if this is unacceptable or answered elsewhere, but I've spent the last hour and a half looking for information on it, and have come up with nothing I can use. I'm brand spanking new to Python and have been given an assignment to pull an IP from a site. I'm able to get my program to read the site, but I'm simply unable to figure out what to do next. Every answer that remotely comes close to what I want is beyond my programming capabilities to the point that I just don't understand it, and tutorials don't actually get at the specific problem I'm having. Again, if there's any document or text I can read instead of wasting time, please send me that way.

```
import urllib.request
site = urllib.request.urlopen("http://homer.wcitac.org/~sec290/hwk2/")
print (site.read())
IP = site[10]
print (IP)
```

I know, it's simplistic, but I've only been doing this for a little while. As far as I can tell, it should print back the 10th (9th on the page) character so I have a starting point, so I can then use a colon to find the characters I want, but it's giving me "TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' object does not support indexing", and I've no idea what that means.

Comment: this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370361/get-ip-address-of-url-in-python

Comment: fyi, `site[10]` would be the eleventh element not the ninth

Answer (score 1):

You have the `site` variable pointed to the return value of `urllib.request.urlopen`.  In the next line, you call `site.read()`, which returns a string.  In short, `site` is not referencing a string; it's referencing a response object which can be used to *get* the string content.

Since you already know `site.read()` returns a string, why not capture *that* as a variable and use it?

```
content = site.read()
print(content)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Would you happen to have a very basic resource on how to use the find function in python as well?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the results of `site.read()`, store it in a variable, which will be a string containing all the text of the page, which you can then do with whatever you need to.