# HTTPResponse Error in urllib python

Tags: python, json, pandas, urllib3

I'm trying to use pandas to read coinmarketcap API . 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589031/7159086
I used the above link to form a basic query using json_normalize but I am getting the below error -

```
'HTTPResponse' object does not support indexing .
```

My Query :-

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

pd.io.json.json_normalize(urlopen('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10'))
```

Output :-

```
TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' object does not support indexing
```

I am running this code in Jupyter Notebook with pandas version `0.20.3` 
I saw this post also - [Retreiving data from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222415/retreiving-data-from-a-website)

But I was not able to solve my issue still .
Please tell how to approach this problem . Further , I want `name` field as the index column which I am not able to get due to nested json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlopen` produces an `HttpResponse` object, not a json string.  You need to call its `read` method to get the json.

Change

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(urlopen('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10'))
```

to

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(urlopen('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10').read())
```

#### Update

`json_normalize` [expects deserialised json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html), so you need to load the json before passing it to `json_normalize`

```
resp = urlopen('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10')
data = json.load(resp)
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
```

Comment: I am still getting below error - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'