# How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library ? in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am making HTTP requests using the requests library in python, but I need the ip address from the server that responded the http request and I'm trying to avoid to make two calls (and possibly having a different ip address from the one that responded the request.

Is that possible? Does any python http library allows me to do that?

i'm also using proxy for the request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get IP address of url in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370361/get-ip-address-of-url-in-python)

Comment: i'm getting this error @LaundroMat  File "search.py", line 58
    print socket.gethostbyname(page)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent         i'm using this line print socket.gethostbyname(page) inside loop

Comment: That's an indentation error. Can you paste your code [on repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python) and share it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use socket for get IP Addres
Example : I Will use Socket + Requests for get status code + ip addres :

```
import socket
import requests


url = 'www.google.com'
sock = socket.gethostbyname(url)
url2 = 'http://www.google.com'
request = requests.get(url2)
if request.status_code == 200:
    status = 'HTTP 200 : OK'
elif request.status_code == 302:
    status = 'HTTP 302 : Redirect'
elif request.status_code == 404:
    status = 'HTTP 404 : NOT FOUND'
else:
    status = 'Unknow Status'
print "[+] URL : " + url + "\n"
print "[+] IP Addres : " + sock + "\n"
print "[+] Reponse Status : " + status
```