# PC name display for SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, linux, http

When I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port>` on my office network, I can get my full PC name displayed in the log output.

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 59992 ...
<pc name> - - [04/Feb/2014 04:59:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But when I run the same in my home network or locally host it, the logs only display the IP address which accessed the service.

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 59992 ...
<my ip> - - [04/Feb/2014 04:59:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Is there any way I could make my home network do the same?

Comment: Install a DNS server on your local network that answers reverse IP requests. This is not a Python problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Is it possible to access the ip<-->PC_name mapping on my office network using python?

Comment: [How can I do DNS lookups in Python, including referring to /etc/hosts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2805231)