# Python - validate a url as having a domain name or ip address

Tags: python, url

I need to validate a url in Python and ensure that the host/netloc component is a domain name or ip v4/v6 address.

Most StackOverflow Q&As on this general topic say to "just use `urlparse`".  That is not applicable to this situation.

I have already used `urlparse` to validate that I do indeed have a url.

The problem is that I need to further validate the `.netloc` from urlparse to ensure that I am getting a Domain Name OR IP Address, and not just a hostname.

Let me illustrate:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
```

This works as expected / desired :

```
>>> ## domain name
>>> print urlparse("http://example.com").netloc
example.com

>>> ## ipv4
>>> print urlparse("http://255.255.255.255").netloc
255.255.255.255

>>> ## acceptable hostname
>>> print urlparse("http://localhost").netloc
localhost
```

But I often run into typos that will let a malformed URL slip through.  Someone might accidentally miss a '.' in a domain name:

```
>>> ## valid hostname, but unacceptable
>>> print urlparse("http://examplecom").netloc
examplecom
```

`examplecom` is indeed a valid hostname, and could exist on a network, but it is not a valid domain name.

There also doesn't seem to be any rules enforced for IP Addresses  :

```
>>> print urlparse("http://266.266.266.266").netloc
266.266.266.266

>>> print urlparse("http://999.999.999.999.999").netloc
999.999.999.999.999
```

Comment: `http://999.999.999.999.999` is a valid address. If you want to see if a domain exist, you can do a DNS lookup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805231/how-can-i-do-dns-lookups-in-python-including-referring-to-etc-hosts

Comment: `999.999.999.999.999` is not a valid address according to the ipv4 or ipv6 standards, which I noted as a requirement in the first sentence.

Answer (score 5):

I think this does what you want:

```
import socket
def good_netloc(netloc):
    try:
        socket.gethostbyname(netloc)
        return True
    except:
        return False

print good_netloc("google.com")
print good_netloc("googlecom")
print good_netloc("10.1.1.1")
print good_netloc("999.999.999.999")
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
lap:~$ python tmp.py
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks.  This could get the job done in many situations, but not all.  `socket.gethostbyname` depends on a DNS lookup, so the computer would have to be connected to the internet.  It also validates that a given domain name has an active DNS record -- so "once active" or "future" domain names all fail ( ie `example.com` passes but `foo.example.com` fails )

Comment: It uses the resolution order, so it shows whether or not the name is currently valid.  (If you add a host to the /etc/hosts file, it will use that.)  I'm not sure I follow your comment about "once active or future".  Are you saying you want it to return True for anything that *could be* (but is not necessarily currently) a valid DNS name?