# How to do this (check requests status codes) in Python concurrently or in parallel?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-requests

Here's what I'm doing:

- Get words from a text file - every word is on a separate line.
- Add `http://www.` and `.com` to words to create a url.
- Get the URL with requests.
- Find out if it's a free domain or not (based on status codes and
  error in connection/other error).
- Add free domains to a text file.
- Time it all.

I've kind of made it work so far but it's very slow. The text file has 350 000 words. How would I go about doing this concurrently or in parallel? Also which would be a better choice for this task?

Here's my code:

```
import requests, time

start = time.time()

with open('words1.txt','r') as f:
    words = []
    for item in f:
        words.append(item.strip())

for w in words:
    url = 'http://www.'+w+'.com'
    try:
        header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
        codes = [200,201,202,203,204,205,206,300,301,302,303,307,308,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,500,501,502,503]
        if r.status_code in codes:
            print(url,': Known Status Code > Unavailable')
        else:
            print(url,': Unknown Status Code > Probably Free')
            with open('available.txt','a') as myfile:
                myfile.write(url+'\n')
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print(url,' : Connection Error > Probably Free')
        with open('available.txt','a') as myfile:
            myfile.write(url+'\n')
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        print('http error')
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print('timeout error')
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print('too many redirects')

end = time.time()
print('\n')
print(end-start, 'seconds')
print((end-start)/60,'minutes')
print(((end-start)/60)/60,'hours')
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I got it to work. Thanks for the help **Kendas** and **DeepSpace**!
Here's a quick test:

100 words - 22 sec

1000 words - 285 sec

Not too fast but way faster than my first try.

Seems like gevent + socket is the way to go.

Please let me know if you have any tips on making this better/faster.

Here's the code:

```
import gevent,time
from gevent import socket

start = time.time()

words = []
with open('words1000.txt','r') as f:
    for item in f:
        words.append(item.strip())

urls = ['www.{}.com'.format(w) for w in words]

jobs = [gevent.spawn(socket.gethostbyname, url) for url in urls]

gevent.joinall(jobs)

values = {url:job.value for (url,job) in zip(urls,jobs)}
freeDomains = []
for (v,job,url) in zip(values,jobs,urls):
    if job.value == None:
        freeDomains.append(url)
        with open('availableds.txt','a') as myFile:
            myFile.write(url+'\n')

print(freeDomains)
end = time.time()
print(end-start,'seconds')
print((end-start)/60,'minutes')
print((end-start)/3600,'hours')
```

Comment: If you're only interested in whether the domain is registered or not, another approach might be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805231/how-can-i-do-dns-lookups-in-python-including-referring-to-etc-hosts

Comment: Yes, that's what I need - availability. What are you suggesting - dnspython?

Comment: no, the `socket` solutions should be fine

Comment: Will look into this. Thank you.

Comment: @Kendas I'm testing this now. Any tips on making this run concurrently/ in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

[grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) (the concurrent version of requests) makes this pretty easy.
It will also help to use `.format` and not redefining `header` every iteration

```
import grequests

def exception_handler(request, exception):
    print(exception)

with open('words1.txt','r') as f:
    words = []
    for item in f:
        words.append(item.strip())
urls = ['http://www.{}.com'.format(w) for w in words]

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

requests = [grequests.get(url) for url in urls]

responses = grequests.map(requests, exception_handler=exception_handler)

for resp in responses:
    if resp:
         print(resp.status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, I'm getting: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Thisplaynaymm Post the full stacktrace

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roae\Desktop\wswp\grequests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import grequests
  File "C:\Users\roae\Desktop\wswp\grequests.py", line 14, in <module>
    requests = [grequests.get(url) for url in urls]
  File "C:\Users\roae\Desktop\wswp\grequests.py", line 14, in <listcomp>
    requests = [grequests.get(url) for url in urls]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Thisplaynaymm Don't name your own script `grequests.py`. It imports itself.

Comment: That was silly. Sorry about that. So, the script is running but I'm not getting anything (updates). Also, how would I time this and write the free domains to a text file?