# Running list of domain name to get IP address

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run "host domain.com" by getting in URL

```
for url in list:

Host = "host %s" % url

IPADDRESS = subprocess.check_output(HOST, shell=True)

print IPADDRESS
```

Comment: New to programming.. have a list of domain names , which i wanted to run host command and save the result in IPADDRESS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do DNS lookups in Python, including referring to /etc/hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805231/how-can-i-do-dns-lookups-in-python-including-referring-to-etc-hosts)

Comment: What does `IPADDRESS = subprocess.check_output(['host', url])` do for you?

Answer (score 0):

for url in list:

```
os.system("host %s | grep 'has address' | sort -u" % (url))
```

Comment: want to use subprocess.check_output but atleast it is popping some results.. where still grep command is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import subprocess
 list = ("/root/cisco/indexlist.txt","r") 
 for hostname in list:
 p1 = subprocess.Popen(['host', hostname],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'IP ADDRESS'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 p3 = subprocess.Popen(['sort','-u'],stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 print (p3.communicate()[0])
```

Comment: **THOUGHT IT WOULD BE USEFUL TO SOME ONE**Checked and its working